# How to download large files (>1GB) with httpClient in angular?

Tags: angular, httpclient, visual-web-developer

I am working on angular 11 which uses httpClient method to download files from the server. This works fine for small size files. But for large files (approx 1GB), the download takes a lot of time although I get a link in the console.log (something like https://999.99.999.99:99999/DownloadFileServlet?filename=/tmp/ab/1607023356995.tar) after some seconds. If I click on this link, the download would start immediately, but otherwise, it would take a lot of time.

Here is my code:

```
            this.downloads.download(this.downloadInfo.filePathName)
             .subscribe(blob => {
                saveAs(blob, 'new_file_name'); 
                this.isContentLoading = false;
              }, 
             err => {
              this.isContentLoading = false;
              const message: LogMessage = {severity: Severity.ERROR, message: "Download not finished"};
              this.logMessageService.log(message);
              }
            );  

           download(fileName: string): Observable<Blob> {   
            return this.https.get(`https://${this.environment.path}/ab/DownloadFileServlet? 
            filename=${fileName}`,
            {
              responseType: "blob",
               withCredentials: true,
               reportProgress: true
            });
          }
```

Please share your experience with how can I efficiently download large files with this method.

Comment: @RandyCasburn corrected.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are indicating here

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you provide a link for downloading the file directly from your server and add it normally to `<a>` tag and don't do it through `httpClient`.

Comment: Can you please describe in a bit more detail @igor_c. Thanks

Comment: Normally you can download a file from any website through link like `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`. You just put your file url in the `href` attribute, user clicks on it and downloads file and you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of using the httpClient, if I directly provide the download link to window.location.href like:
return window.location.href = `https://${this.environment.path}/DownloadFileServlet?filename=${fileName}`

The download starts much faster. Though I am sure if this is the proper solution, would be happy to know a better idea if there is.